# Code runs perfectly when using SSH, but shows syntax error when compiling with Geany

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error, raspberry-pi3, geany

This is the screen shot of the 'geany' of my raspberry pi:

[image]

I could not figure out what is going on with this code, it is part of my program and each time I use 'geany' to run it, it shows syntax error.

But when I use python script or directly use SSH to run python, the code runs perfectly well.

Is it that I did not set 'geany''s parameter well or any other problem. Hopefully someone could help me figure it out ! Thanks!

Comment: Geany is using Python 2, where `input` evaluates the input you supply. You'll need to change it to point to Python 3.

Comment: Thanks! it is working!